# "java.exe" exited with code 1 Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

When i create an empty project and click build to my android phone, i face this problem

> "java.exe" exited with code 1

and in output tab i see this messages 
[Click to see Output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8KhK.png)

i trying to do these things :

- change java MAX Heap Size to 1G from : Project > App Properties > Android Options > Advanced
- install java JDK 1.8.0_102 and change location from 1.7 to 1.8.0_102 from : Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Setting > Java Development Kit Location
- Clear Solution and re-build

i'm using Visual studio 2015 Enterprise and my phone is Samsung Alpha

please help me to solve this error

Comment: Change Location to Java v 1.7 32 Bit

Comment: @GauravKP SDK 7 requires Java 1.8. Ammar Midani do as the log says and look at the full log to see the exception: http://asish.com.au/xamarin-logs-visual-studio/

Comment: @Gusman
Xamarin need Java 1.7
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

Comment: @GauravKP nope, latest update requires Java 1.8: https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-android-7-0-now-with-more-nougat/

Comment: @GauravKP that doesn't means nothing, the minimum deploy target is independant of the SDK version you use. If the OP installed the latest SDK then it reqires Java 1.8.

Comment: it's not helping @GauravKP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your `obj` and `bin` folder for both projects. (`PCL` and `Android`).

If you're using a custom proguard tool, verify the file encoding is in `utf` or `Ascii`.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this kinds of problem.in my case it was "java.exe" exited with code 2.simply i just **Checked Enable Multi-Desk** and solved my problem.