# Keep getting error "java.exe" exited with code 2 / The package was not properly signed (NO_CERTIFICATES)

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

I created an empty Xamarin.Forms project on Visual Studio 2019 for Android and IOS and without adding any code and this error popped up without letting me build the project.

`MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.`

I have looked into this and I've tried

- Deleting bin and obj file from Xamarin.Android and rebuild
- Repairing Visual Studio
- Untick the sign Apk option on Android properties
- Checking Multi-Dex on Android properties
- Uninstalling and installing Visual Studio 2019 again
- Changing the sdk file path like so [android-sdk path containing "space"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45303281/18568045)

And I have looked into this solutions but none of them work for me

- [The package was not properly signed (NO_CERTIFICATES) in running application - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201038/the-package-was-not-properly-signed-no-certificates-in-running-application)
- [Xamarin Andorid Build Always Fails ("java.exe" exited with code 2) - Stack Overflow
  "java.exe" exited with code 2 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122972/xamarin-andorid-build-always-fails-java-exe-exited-with-code-2)
- ["java.exe" exited with code 1 Xamarin C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177856/java-exe-exited-with-code-1-xamarin-c-sharp)

Please help because I don't know what is causing this and I have tried everything.

**EDIT:**
After a couple of times trying to build the project this is the error that shows up:

```
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: The package was not properly signed (NO_CERTIFICATES).
   en Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) en D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:línea 338
   en Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass100_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) en D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:línea 803
   en System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackageAsync>d__12.MoveNext() en D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Devices\AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:línea 206
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackageAsync>d__12.MoveNext() en D:\a\_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Devices\AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:línea 223
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.<InstallPackage>d__101.MoveNext() en /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:línea 338
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.<InstallPackage>d__101.MoveNext() en /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:línea 355
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.<RunTaskAsync>d__96.MoveNext() en /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:línea 212           0   Compilación
```

Comment: Please check in Tools --> Options --> Xamarin --> Android Settings
which JDK are you using.
Mine is C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot
and it is working with no issues

Comment: Try 3rd response : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672028/xamarin-forms-java-exe-exited-with-code-2-in-vs-2017?force_isolation=true

Comment: @CyberZeus I had that jdk path in the beggining and didn't work so I changed it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202`

Comment: @jdweng I'm gessing I need to add those two labels `<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>` and
 `<AndroidLinkTool>r8</AndroidLinkTool>` on my Android.csproj `<PropertyGroup>`

Comment: What Android SDK are you targeting?

Comment: @CyberZeus For Android 11

Comment: Try opening the csproj file with notepad.  There is a signing property that you can set to false.

Comment: @jdweng I can't find that signing property, I've seen that solution before but I can't find it

Comment: @jdweng Tried the third response and didn't work either

Comment: Try this : <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>

Comment: @jdweng I think it's an issue with some visual studio folder because any project that I create won't let me build

Comment: Probably problem is due to how VS was installed.  When you install an application you can install for just one user or all users.  You probably install for one user and then tried to use with a different users.  You may of installed as a user instead of an Admin.  The Admin install give option to install for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me what worked was just deleting the following:

- Android folder which contains the sdk `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android`
- Eclipse Foundation folder which contains the jdk
- Xamarin folder `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Xamarin`

And then reinstall Visual Studio 2019.

Before it wouldn't let me build any Xamarin project even though I had tried everything people said when referring to this error.

I hope this helped someone in case of having the same issue as me.